# insert nearest p class value into variable

Tags: jquery

I'm guessing im attempting this all wrong. What I want to happen is when a user clicks an email now button (image) jQuery then searches for the closest p tag with the given class name and stores it's value / text into a variable.

Im using:

```
$(".modaltrailertrigger img").click(function() {
    var trailerenq = $(this).closest("p.newmodel");
    alert(trailerenq);
    $("input[name='message']").val(trailerenq);
});
```

the alert is only in there as it wasn't inserting the value into the form but i cant manage to get an alert box with the value up either?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e9mntq5q/

Comment: just dont use alert to debug things, use console.log()

Comment: @johnSmith thats fine but doesn't help me when that returns nothing either.

Comment: Need to see an example of your html

Comment: trailerenq for you is a jquery object. Have you tried trailerenq.text()

Comment: You just need `trailerenq.text()`!

Comment: unfortunately adding .text() still gives no output @DhavalMarthak

Comment: Please provide relevant html in question

Comment: No idea what `<p>` you are wanting since `.modaltrailertrigger` isn't in a `<p>`

Comment: if you look at the code it's clearly p.newmodel :s ".closest("p.newmodel");"